# Having a simple issues. Don't know how to solve and I haven't seen any solutions online

Tags: c++

These letters keep duplicating or changing one another:

```
|| a - u || e - y || w -c || v - b || x - d || z - f ||
```

I haven't been able to solve it by myself, or have seen a solution online.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char zodis[20];
    char zodis2[25];
    char h, ch;
    int l, i, ng, n, k, x;
do{
        cout << "\n\t\t ***** () Hangman () ***** \n\n\n\n";
        cout << "\t\t Enter a word : ";
        cin.get(zodis, 20);
        l=strlen(zodis); 
        char pasir[20]="0";
        n=0;k=0;
        system("CLS");

        for(i=0;i<=20;i++)
            {
        if (zodis[i]=='\0') {zodis2[i]='\0';break;}
        if (zodis[i]!=' ')  zodis2[i]='-'; 
        }
        ng=l+3;
    do{
        cia:
        if (k!=0)
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\t Chosen letters : " << pasir << "\n";
        cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t      " << zodis2 << "\n\n\n Guesses left :  "<< ng << ", choose the next letter : ";
        cin >> ch; 
        system("CLS");
        for ( i=0;i<25;i++ )
        if ( pasir[i] == ch ) 
            {
     cout << "\t\t  Raide : " << ch << " : jau pasirinkote\n";
     goto cia;
     }
     ng--; pasir[k]=ch; pasir[k+1]=',';k+=2;

     for (i=0;i<=20;i++)
     if (zodis[i]==ch || zodis[i]==ch+20 || zodis[i]==ch-20) zodis2[i]=ch;
     if (!strcmp(zodis2,zodis))
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "\n\t\t\t      " << string(zodis) << "\n\n\t\t\t  Correct! :) \n" ; break;
            }
     }
    while(ng > 0 || !strcmp (zodis2,zodis));
    if (strcmp(zodis2,zodis))
        cout << "\n The word was : " << string(zodis) << endl;
        }
    while (ch==0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include the actual assignment text, in full and complete. And please learn how to use a debugger to be able to step through your code statement by statement.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use a debugger? Probably time you learned. Anyway

```
char zodis[20];
for(i=0;i<=20;i++)
    ... zodis[i] ...
```

Already that's an error, the valid indexes for `zodis` are 0 to 19, so `zodis[20]` is an out of bounds array access.

Comment: Oh wow, that actually solved it. It seems that I was just blind for not seeing it earlier.